# Unknown error: cannot connect to Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

Использую в своём скрипте undetected chrome driver, возникает проблема с подключением браузер Unknown error: cannot connect to Chrome. Когда использую на последней версии браузера и устанавливаю браузер из кода автоматически, проблемы не возникает. Но мне необходимо запустить скрипт на версии хрома 109. Запуская на ней с нужным драйвером выдаёт данную ошибку. Также использую pyinstaller перед запуском, но ранее проблем с запуском собранного фала не наблюдал.